# CSS: My "display:inline block" refusing to transform?

Tags: html, css

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewlouis93/NWYeU/)

In the `#text-banner`, which sets the title, the `rotate` transforms are not carried out. I notice that it does work when I set the styling to `position:absolute;`. However, I can't use that, because it has to be `relative`, since it is contained within the `#white_logo`. In addition, this seems to break the borders on the title text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: inline block` should be `display: inline-block`. There's a `-` and not a space between inline and block. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NWYeU/1/

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. Change your code from `inline block` to `inline-block`.

```
 #text_banner {
     border-top-style:solid;
     padding-top:5px;
     border-bottom-style:solid;
     padding-bottom:5px;
     top:45%;
     left:30%;
     color: gray;
     opacity:1;
     font-size:40px;
     transform: rotate(30deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
     /* IE 9 */
     -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
     /* Safari and Chrome */
     display:inline-block;
     /* Change here */
     position:relative;
 }
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C3TfT/